# What's the best way to monitor rabbitmq to make sure everything is running smoothly?

Tags: rabbitmq

Many times, I get:

-Frozen, load goes to 5.0. Can't use my box.
-Just doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information? Is the 'box' hosting the just Rabbit MQ server alone or also the job fetchers/publishers and/or workers? What sort of queue load is there? Is this idle, or under heavy traffic? How many queues have you got? So are you monitoring just the MQ server or the entire platform?

Answer (score 20):

Do following steps:

1.rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

2.service rabbitmq-server restart

3.browse to http://rabbitmq-server-ip:15672

4.login with

```
username: guest
password: guest
```

Dont forget to change your password later.

Comment: Same steps are described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) with some additional information.

Answer (score 17):

As sheki notes, `rabbitmqctl` is your first port of call for diagnostics, and for building monitoring on top of, but it's not suitable for actual monitoring directly being a manual command line.

I've found [DataDog](http://datadoghq.com) very good to monitor both the MQ details, plus the host platform in parallel. e.g. you can watch the queue levels and set alerts on queues backing-up, while also watching the CPU/memory/IO inflicted by these queue levels. It really helps to get ratios of resource usage, and the alerts are good. Having a uniform platform for both infrastructure and application level monitoring is surprisingly rare, but speeds up diagnoses of production issues hugely.

[NewRelic](http://newrelic.com) is similar and also has a [RabbitMQ plugin](https://newrelic.com/plugins/pivotal/95?utm_source=GOOG&utm_medium=adword&utm_content=jboss&utm_campaign=RabbitMQ&utm_term=RabbitMQ&mpc=PS-GOOG-Platform-RabbitMQ-EN-SIGNUP-APAC-RabbitMQmonitoring-RabbitMQ&_kk=monitor%20rabbitmq&_kt=5a25f7d9-52ba-41f9-b9ad-b4fd664aff06), although I've not used this plugin specifically, I've used NR for years and found it invaluable in diagnosing operational issues.

[AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/) is another example. Similarly this allows you to drill down into your app from a high-level dashboard, and visually navigate from problems to causes. It's especially good with visualising the network of a distributed application across various services/servers. I've used this, for example, to find complex problems in .NET applications and SQL Server clusters using 3rd party Web Services (e.g. latency and its consequences to your app over chatty protocols). These things are very difficult to diagnose, especially for developers who are limited to checking their code. Diagnosing operational issues requires a much broader picture.

I gave up trying to even install and configure Nagios. I know it's the 'best' but it's the best of an old breed of self-configured beasts which we don't have time to manage. I didn't even get it going... and eventually turned to the more 'modern' cloud approach. Once you get over the trust factor, it's pretty liberating.

I'm using these APM platforms together* to aggregate data from:

- Windows O/S level Event Logs/Services
- Linux O/S level
- AWS console level
- RDS, EC2
- Apache
- MySQL
- App integrations / custom NR plugins I've written
- Rabbit MQ

**NewRelic can feed into Datadog! So if you are already using NR you don't need to install DD on those hosts as well.*

Being able to view all these levels together gives you a view on the publishers, middleware, MQ servers, workers and front-end app - all in one dashboard.

I would highly recommend an approach like this, because just looking at one server alone leads you to a lot of head-scratching. Seeing an entire stack in one customisable dashboard is just so illuminating it takes most of the guesswork out of it.

Worried about installing these things? I found New Relic to be especially light-weight and unobtrusive. AppDynamics seemed to stress the host a bit more, but mostly that's because you had to run the visualisation tools on the host! (this may have changed). DataDog seems performant, but creates a lot of control panels/icons on the target host (perhaps just a visual impression).

To a four year old question - this answer probably wasn't available in 2011, but in 2015 these once 'startup' style APM services are just tens or hundred dollars a month for an unbelievably rich enterprise-level solution.

Answer (score 16):

There are bunch of RabbitMQ monitoring plugins available for different monitoring systems like Nagios, Zabbix etc.
Look at http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html#management
Using rabbitmqctl is the most straight forward solution to check the status of the node.

```
$ rabbitmqctl status
```

This should tell you the status of the RabbitMQ node.

Answer (score 6):

If you have PRTG (or any probe system with a HTTP sensor check), you can check the server status described at the following page:
https://blog.cdemi.io/monitoring-rabbitmq-in-prtg/

In particular you have to

> **Enable Management Plugin** 
>   The rabbitmq-management plugin provides an HTTP-based API for management and monitoring of your RabbitMQ
>   server, along with a browser-based UI and a command line tool,
>   rabbitmqadmin. The management plugin is included in the RabbitMQ
>   distribution. To enable it, we need to run: rabbitmq-plugins enable
>   rabbitmq_management on the RabbitMQ nodes. For more details on the
>   Management plugin refer to RabbitMQ Documentation.
>
> The web UI is located at: http://server-name:15672/ The HTTP API and
>   its documentation are both located at: http://server-name:15672/api/

Once done, you can check the overview of your server with the API:

```
http://server-name:15672/api/overview
```

Where you have a JSON with all details about the server, active connections, queues, etc.

Comment: You should first go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.2.3\sbin` in Windows before executing `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

Answer (score 0):

This cmd will help you `service rabbitmq-server status` or `$ rabbitmqctl status`

OR try these`service rabbitmq-server stop` and `service rabbitmq-server start` then `service rabbitmq-server status`.

Comment: Any service can appear to be running and still not be ready to respond to requests. This is not an effective approach.